# Listen to port and if request prefix is correct return result

Tags: firewall

I would like to setup Ubuntu to act as a dictionary . It should accept string from client and if string prefix is correct (acts as one time password) then get the rest of the string, process it and return result to client. For example, return string length. Finally, if the prefix is wrong - return “port closed”.
Knockd has similar port opening feature, but is it possible to do it with core Linux tools without third party software?